# Blocking file from network location

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I developed small windows service for my company's needs, and I recieved claim about files being blocked(exe, and dll distributed via mail), so user have to go to the properties of each exe or dll and uncheck "block" etc. to install it. I was ask if I can change this behaviour. Is there a way, so I (developer) can change this behaviour on my side?

Answer (score 1):

Don't distribute it by email.  Instead, stand up a small web server and host the files there. Then include in the email the link to the files you want to distribute.  Most mail clients will block any exe or dlls being sent as attachments.